# JavaScript - Backtracking code?

Tags: javascript

I'm just opened FireBug and saw this on my site

```
<div style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Is there a way to backtrack this code and see where it originated from as it's not hardcoded?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that, but your site should have some tell-tale signs like long lines of `eval()` ed JavaScript code or similar somewhere.

Comment: At most there might be eval() in the jQuery core, but it hasn't behaved like this before.. My code does not have a single eval() anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to WHAT made this is - Google Maps. No way around that.
So that is solved.
It does however not answer the actual question - Is there a way to backtrack dynamic code to it's origin?